# ThreeJS Flickering on iOS

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I started to play around with ThreeJS and StereoEffects:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/829184/tmp/threejs_skybox/index.html

Everything works great on Chrome Desktop, but on iOS8 on iPhone 6 and 5 the whole scenes starts flickering.

Is there something wrong with my code? (See link above)

Comment: Could you able to resolve the issue? I am facing the same issue